# Customising Google Maps breaks highway label blocks

Tags: google, javascript, map

I'm trying to customise a Google map to use shades of a particular colour. It's working nicely except the blocks that contain major road names / numbers is illegible. I've figured out how to target styles to those elements, but setting the 'color' value sets both text and background to that colour. And no adjusting of saturation, gamma, lightness etc seems to make the text legible.

```
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.766472,0.284732);
    var styles = [
        {
            stylers: [
                { "gamma": 0.75 },
                { "hue": "#607C75" },
                { "saturation": -75 },
                { "lightness": 0 }
            ]
        },{
            featureType: "water",
            stylers: [
                {color: "#607C75"}
            ]
        }
    ];
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        title:"Living, dining, bedrooms by David Salmon"
    });
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    map.setOptions({styles: styles});
    marker.setMap(map);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For the labels of the roads you don't have to set the color of the label, but only style the 'hue', 'saturation' and 'lightness'. For example:

```
var styles = [
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
            { "Hue": "#0a9ad7" },
            { "saturation": 100 },
            { "lightness" : -20 }
        ]
    }
]
```

By changing the saturation and lightness you can change the difference between the line around the label and the color of the label itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to individually style the labels.text.fill and the labels.text.stroke.

```
var styles = [  { stylers: [{ hue: "#E29FC7" }]  },
    { featureType: "all", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]  },
    { featureType: "road", elementType: "all", stylers: [{ visibility: "simplified" }]  },
    { featureType: "road.arterial", stylers: [{ color: "#702076" }, { lightness: 50 }]  },
    { featureType: "road.highway", stylers: [{ color: "#702076" }, { lightness: 50 }]  },
    { featureType: "road.local", stylers: [{ color: "#e00073" }, { lightness: 50 }]  },
    { featureType: "road", elementType: "labels.text.stroke", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]  },
    { featureType: "road", elementType: "labels.text.fill", stylers: [{ color: "#000000" },{ lightness:5 },{ visibility: "on" }]  },
    { featureType: "road", elementType: "labels.icon", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]  },
    { featureType: "water", stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }]  },
    { featureType: "administrative", elementType: "labels.text.stroke", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]  },
    { featureType: "administrative", elementType: "labels.text.fill", stylers: [{ color: "#000000" },{ lightness:5 },{ visibility: "on" }]  },
];
```